# Converting app engine search API query to elasticsearch query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, elasticsearch, google-search-api

I'm migrating my existing python 2.7 project from app engine. In my code, there's extensive use of [Document Search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/). I'm using [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html) to replace it outside the app engine.

I've created a base handler to replace the creation and deletion of documents with Elastic search handler. But I'm stuck at searching the documents.

In the app engine search API, there are so many different types of queries available (check out [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/query_strings)) and I'm thinking to make a single function to replace those queries with the elastic search compatible query.

For example, 
a simple Search API query looks like:

```
search_query = "forFromDate : 2019-06-01 forToDate : 2019-07-01"
```

but the same query for elastic search would be like:

```
es_query = {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "forToDate": "2019-07-01"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "forFromDate": "2019-06-01"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I can achieve such simple query conversion with the simple python function, but for complex queries, it's difficult to manage. Any idea of how to convert such queries?? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are too many combinations of queries, so you should analyze queries fields (bool, must, should, match, match-all, multi_match, fuzzines, wildcard .... ) and do some kind of mapping for your desired input string. The difficult and cost is so high

Comment: Also worth investigating [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) and [`simple_query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html)